Issue with MongoDB Query Using $ne: null on Array Fields
Context
We are working with MongoDB queries in a Node.js application, where we need to filter documents based on whether an array field (specifically, a field within a nested array) exists and is not null.
Consider the following sample document:
{
  "name": "Event1",
  "campaigns": [
    {
      "id": "id1",
      "eID": "eID1"
    }
  ]
}

Problem:
We’ve been using the following MongoDB queries:

Query with $exists:

{ "campaigns.eID": { $exists: true } }

Result: This works as expected, returning documents where the eID field exists within any element of the campaigns array.

Query with $ne: null:

{ "campaigns.eID": { $ne: null } }

Result: This query does not work as expected in our Node.js application. It returns inconsistent results: sometimes it fails to match documents where eID is not null or undefined.
Additional Observations

When testing these queries in MongoDB Compass:

The $exists query consistently returns correct results for all team members.
The $ne: null query works correctly in MongoDB Compass for me, but it does not work for my colleague, even though we are using the same query on the same data.



Questions

Why is the $ne: null query behaving inconsistently across different environments (Node.js vs MongoDB Compass)?
Is there a known issue or a best practice when using $ne: null with array fields, particularly in nested documents?
Should we avoid using $ne: null in this context, and instead always use $exists?


1. Provide example data & output results where $ne: null gives inconsistent results for different people. 2. $exists: true and $ne: null test for different things, in most contexts. 3. You're checking an array, so that's probably not the correct query anyway. Which campaigns do you want to find? Campaigns which have at least one eID missing? Campaigns which have at least one eID: null? Campaigns which have no missing or null eID?

First and foremost, I sincerely apologize for the delayed response. I truly appreciate your patience.

Hear you go:
1. If I query {'campaigns.eID': {'$ne': null}}, at one time it
will give the documents which has campaigns.eID, same as sample document, at other times it returns with documents which doesn't have campaigns.eID. Eg:
[{"name":"Event1","campaigns":[{"id":"id1","eID":"eID1"}]},{"name":"Event2","campaigns":[]}]
3. To find documents where the campaigns array contains at least one element and with a non-null eID.
